# Architectural Hierarchy of AngularJS Application

Tags: angularjs

My company has started transitioning to use AngularJS and we are beginning to add more and more features using the framework.  Before, I didn't really have a solid file structure and modularization of the application, but now that it is growing I want to set up the proper structure.

I am having troubles getting some Factories to work that I want to be global to the entire application.  I have a main module like

```
angular.module('app', ['app.dashboard', 'app.store', 'app.login', 'app.media'])
```

and then a couple sub modules like

```
angular.module('app.dashboard', [])
angular.module('app.store', [])
angular.module('app.login', [])
angular.module('app.media', [])
```

I want to create an factory call `API` that uses `$resource`s to create a RESTful service to consume our Web API.  I have been using this factory all along and know it works, now I am just trying to re-structure everything.  The factory exists on the `app` module, therefore I thought that all submodules would have access to this, but I think the DI is going the opposite direction and therefore the submodules do not get any factories or services from the root `app` module.

What is the best practice in terms of create services like an API service that is global to the entire application?

Comment: Here you go http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/02/an-angularjs-style-guide-and-best.html

Comment: I've seen this article already, but it did not really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, this service used globally should be defined in its own module, and all the modules using it should depend on it.

This is important if you plan to use this module in a separate application though, in order to be able to extract it without needing to extract application-specific components. But if you use it in a single application, it doesn't matter much, since in the end, all the components of all the modules loaded by application (recursively) are available everywhere.

Comment: So it is standard to just have a module like `angular.module('app.API', [])` that has the factory, then just change the modules to be like `angular.module('app.dashboard', ['app.API'])`?

Comment: Nothing is standard. But that's the cleanest way to model the actual dependencies of your modules: the components in API don't depend on the other ones of the app, and the components in the other modules of the app all depend on the components in the API module.

Comment: Could we instead include `app` into all the submodules? like `angular.module('app.dashboard', ['app'])`? Or is that bad?

Comment: That won't work: the app is composed of dashboard, store, etc. The dashboard is not composed of the app. And when you'll use ng-app="app", if "app" doesn't depend on the dashboard, store and other modules, they won't be loaded.

Comment: Oh I see. Hmmm ok I will attempt to re-structure the modules like you said